# SDL fscanf Function Issue

Tags: c++, sdl, scanf

I created a function which loads a very basic map file of the form:

```
1:1 2:1 1:1 2:2 2:2 2:2 ...
................... 2:1 1:1
```

However, when using `fscanf` to read in the file, I am getting some very odd behaviour.

Looking at the `FILE` variable I have set up to read the map, the `base` element of the 'stream' of the `FILE` seems to have read the file perfectly. However, the `_ptr` of the 'stream' of the `FILE` is missing the first number, and the last. So it gets read as:

```
:1 2:1 1:1 2:2 2:2 2:2 ...
................... 2:1 1:
```

and is generating an error.

Here is my function:

```
/**
 *  loads a map
 */
bool Map::LoadMap(char* tFile)
{
    FILE* FileHandle = fopen(tFile, "r");           // opens map file for reading

    if (FileHandle == NULL)                         // returns if the map file does not exist
        return false;

    for(int Y = 0; Y < MAP_HEIGHT; Y++)             // iterates through each row
    {
        for(int X = 0; X < MAP_WIDTH; X++)          // iterates through each column
        {
            Node    tNode;                          // temp node to put in the map matrix

            int     tTypeID     = 0;
            int     tNodeCost   = 0;

            fscanf(FileHandle, "%d:%d", tTypeID, tNodeCost);

            tNode.SetPosition(X, Y);
            tNode.SetType(tTypeID);
            tNode.SetNodeCost(tNodeCost);

            mMap[X][Y]      = tNode;                // inserts temp node into list
        }
        fscanf(FileHandle, "\n");
    }

    fclose(FileHandle);

    return true;
}
```

Why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the addresses of the variables to `fscanf()`:

```
fscanf(FileHandle, "%d:%d", &tTypeID, &tNodeCost);
```

Recommend checking the return value of `fscanf()` to ensure success:

```
// fscanf() returns the number of assignments made or EOF.
if (2 == fscanf(FileHandle, "%d:%d", &tTypeID, &tNodeCost))
{
}
```